# Were the parallel dimensions in Sliders parallel in time?

Tags: sliders

What I mean is, did time flow at the same rate in each dimension?

Some dimensions were many years advanced beyond “our” dimension while others were seemingly far behind.

Was it ever mentioned if time was variable when they went between dimensions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[As Time Goes By](http://sliders.wikia.com/wiki/As_Time_Goes_By) is the best example of this.  Time is moving backwards in chunks at a time, so they arrive on the next Earth at the *end* of their Slide, and leave at the *beginning*.

[The Guardian](http://sliders.wikia.com/wiki/The_Guardian) is not a good example; the reason they appeared to be in the past was that days were a fraction of a second longer on that Earth, and have been for thousands of years at minimum.  No time travel/time shifting was involved.

Comment: May I ask why this was downvoted?

Comment: You may ask. Whether you get an answer is another matter.

Answer (score 6):

There were a number of episodes where time flowed differently. "As Time Goes By" and "The Guardian" are two examples. As I recall, there was a techno-babble discussion about this in both these episodes.